# Creating an SQL query in drupal

Tags: sql, drupal

Hi I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this. I am familiar with Views, but I'm interested in outputting to a specific variable, not a table, list, etc.

Here is what I'm trying to do:
for each taxonomy term, echo the term, count how many users have a node with that term and echo that count.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the default Views module as it doesn't offer this kind of aggregation function. However, with the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) module you can add the desired behaviour. When you would get a (grouped) table in standard Views, this module is able to count rows for each group (and do much more like sum and average) so you would get a single row per taxonomy term and the number of nodes/users associated to that term.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Can you give me some direction to get started with how to create this specific view? I just installed Aggregator Plus and it's very overwhelming.

Comment: I would create a view of taxonomy terms, add relationships for nodes and authors and then group the view by taxonomy term and author id. With Aggregator Plus you can then just use the count function. Depends pretty much on your set up and the possible relations.